# Windows Server 2008 application high ram usage case RDP to hang up

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Is there any way to check in some logs files which application on my Windows Server 2008 is building up RAM usage over time? I believe some application is doing that and when I connect via RDP I got hang up... can't do anything really. After reboot everything works. Is there anyway to check that in logfiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Task Manager. Look at the memory used by each application. Watch it for a while. Is there an application in that list who's memory usage keeps growing and doesn't go back down?

More in-depth analysis can be done with tools such as Perfmon (Performance Monitor,) with which you can watch and log many different counters that correspond to many different types of memory usage.

Then there's Windows Performance Toolkit, which is an *extreme* logging method that will tell exactly where your memory is going millisecond-by-millisecond.

Then you have a tool such as Procdump, which you can set up to take a process memory dump of a given process under certain circumstances, such as when it has exceeded X% CPU usage for Y minutes, or X% memory usage for Y minutes, etc.